# How do I pass over a argument in a function?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to skip over an argument in a function or a constructor. I believe there was, but whenever I try to do it with a constructor I get an error message.

Javascript

```
 function Black(race, nation ){
        this.race = race ||"black";
        this.nation = nation || "unknown";


    }

    black1 = new Black( ,"America");
    black2 = new Black(  ,"UK");
    black3 = new Black( ,"S America");

    console.log(black1, black2, black3);
```

Comment: Pass `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `var black1 = new Black(null, "America");`